# How to convert DIV tags in to P tag if div does not have any style attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am working on a text editor and when the page renders I am trying to convert all `<div>` tag in to `<p>` tag if there is no style attribute in the  tag using following javascript regex. (Soruce html at the end)

```
// if <div> has any attribute then do not convert in <p> tag
str = str.replace(/<div>([\w\W]*?)<\/div>/gi, '<p>$2</p>');
```

But the output of this regx is weird

OUTPUT HTML: Notice the unexpected `'<p>$2</p>'` at the end and Zoltan and congratulation text goes missing.

```
<br>
@abc Semantics
<br>
<a href="http://abc.com">http://abc.com</a>
<br>
xxxx5555
<br>
Mail address:
<a target="blank" href="/abc-abc-semantics">@abc</a>
<br>
<br>
<b>
Sub:
</b>
<br>
<br>
Hi abc,&nbsp;<p>$2</p><p>$2</p>;<p>$2</p><p>$2</p>
```

//Original HTML on which I am applying the regx

```
<br> 
  @abc Semantics 
<br> 
  <a href="http://abc.com">http://abc.com</a> 
<br> 
  xxxx5555 
<br> 
  Mail address: <a href="/abc-abc-semantics" target="blank">@abc</a> 
<br> 
<br> 
  <b> Sub: </b> 
<br> <br> 
Hi abc,&nbsp;
<div><br></div>

<div>congratulations :D</div>

<div><br></div>
;
<div>Zoltan</div>
```

Comment: I can add more details to it ... if required.

Comment: `str` is the original html string pasted above. On which I am trying to apply the regex.

Comment: What will you do with nested divs?

Comment: exactly pstr ... I am struggling with that, still have not figured out a solution. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: FYI! when I am trying this `replace(/<div(.*?)>([\w\W]*?)<\/div>/gi, '<p>$2</p>')` it converts all div to `<p>` tag looses all style or any other attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `group 2` in your `regex`, so `$2` is taken as `$2` only, and no replacement it done.

You need to use `$1`: -

```
str = str.replace(/<div>([\w\W]*?)<\/div>/gi, '<p>$1</p>');
```

See demo on http://fiddle.re/v0jb

Comment: Will this only convert if there is no attribute in div tag? What if there is an attribute and still convert? what to change?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$1` and not `$2`, as there is no group 2 in your regex.

So the new code will be:

```
str = str.replace(/<div>([\w\W]*?)<\/div>/gi, '<p>$1</p>');
```